# kaggle could not download resnet50 pretrained model

Tags: python, keras, kaggle, resnet

I am trying to use resnet50 pretrained model on Kaggle kernel.

But, when I run the following code, Error occurs and it could not download the pretrained model. How Can I make it work?

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np

model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
```

Error:

> -> 1318                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))    1319
>   except OSError as err: # timeout error
>   ...
>
> Exception: URL fetch failure on
>   https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.2/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5:
>   None -- [Errno -2] Name or service not known

All logs:

> Using TensorFlow backend.
>   /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning:
>   compiletime version 3.5 of module
>   'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime
>   version 3.6   return f(*args, **kwds)
>
> Downloading data from
>   https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.2/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last) /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in do_open(self,
>   http_class, req, **http_conn_args)    1317
>   h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
>   -> 1318                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))    1319
>   except OSError as err: # timeout error
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in request(self, method, url,
>   body, headers, encode_chunked)    1238         """Send a complete
>   request to the server."""
>   -> 1239         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)    1240
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _send_request(self, method,
>   url, body, headers, encode_chunked)    1284             body =
>   _encode(body, 'body')
>   -> 1285         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)    1286
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in endheaders(self,
>   message_body, encode_chunked)    1233             raise
>   CannotSendHeader()
>   -> 1234         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)    1235
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _send_output(self,
>   message_body, encode_chunked)    1025         del self._buffer[:]
>   -> 1026         self.send(msg)    1027
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in send(self, data)
>       963             if self.auto_open:
>   --> 964                 self.connect()
>       965             else:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in connect(self)    1391 
>   -> 1392             super().connect()    1393
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in connect(self)
>       935         self.sock = self._create_connection(
>   --> 936             (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
>       937         self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/socket.py in create_connection(address,
>   timeout, source_address)
>       703     err = None
>   --> 704     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
>       705         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family,
>   type, proto, flags)
>       744     addrlist = []
>   --> 745     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
>       746         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
>
> gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.0.6-py3.6.egg/keras/utils/data_utils.py
>   in get_file(fname, origin, untar, md5_hash, file_hash, cache_subdir,
>   hash_algorithm, extract, archive_format, cache_dir)
>       219             try:
>   --> 220                 urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
>       221             except URLError as e:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlretrieve(url,
>   filename, reporthook, data)
>       247 
>   --> 248     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
>       249         headers = fp.info()
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data,
>   timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
>       222         opener = _opener
>   --> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>       224
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl,
>   data, timeout)
>       525 
>   --> 526         response = self._open(req, data)
>       527
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _open(self, req, data)
>       543         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
>   --> 544                                   '_open', req)
>       545         if result:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain,
>   kind, meth_name, *args)
>       503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
>   --> 504             result = func(*args)
>       505             if result is not None:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in https_open(self, req)
>   1360             return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
>   -> 1361                 context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)    1362
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in do_open(self,
>   http_class, req, **http_conn_args)    1319             except OSError
>   as err: # timeout error
>   -> 1320                 raise URLError(err)    1321             r = h.getresponse()
>
> URLError:
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         4 import numpy as np
>         5 
>   ----> 6 model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.0.6-py3.6.egg/keras/applications/resnet50.py in ResNet50(include_top, weights, input_tensor, input_shape, pooling,
>   classes)
>       261                                     WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP,
>       262                                     cache_subdir='models',
>   --> 263                                     md5_hash='a268eb855778b3df3c7506639542a6af')
>       264         model.load_weights(weights_path)
>       265         if K.backend() == 'theano':
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Keras-2.0.6-py3.6.egg/keras/utils/data_utils.py
>   in get_file(fname, origin, untar, md5_hash, file_hash, cache_subdir,
>   hash_algorithm, extract, archive_format, cache_dir)
>       220                 urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
>       221             except URLError as e:
>   --> 222                 raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
>       223             except HTTPError as e:
>       224                 raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.code, e.msg))
>
> Exception: URL fetch failure on
>   https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.2/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5:
>   None -- [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: Can you access this file from a browser on the computer you are trying to download it on?

Comment: https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.2/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5: is not reachable, when I remove ':' at the end, it is reachable. When I run same code in local jupyter it downlaods model.

Answer (score 16):

Internet setting comes off as default on kaggle. If you turn on it, you can download the pre-trained models.

On the right side of the kernel, you will see the settings you can enable the Internet there.
[image]

Comment: Thanks this helped me

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Kaggle kernels run in isolated containers without Internet access. All training models must be set up and attached as data sets. You can try searching for what you need within the public dataset library. For example, Resnet50 can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/keras/resnet50

Comment: could you provide a link which mention that kaggle run container in isolation without internet access ?

Answer (score 0):

Now Day to Fix This Error Go to Right (<) like this sign inside open the Notebook

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).